# posting variable from php file to another php file

Tags: php

I show similar threads, but could not get clear through them.

page1.php

```
<?php
   $id = 1234;
   //Post $id to page2.php   
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
      $user_id=$_POST['id']; //should receive id posted from page1.php
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are not sending the `id` parameter to your **`Page2.php`**

**`Page1.php`**

```
<?php
   $id = 1234;
   header("location:page2.php?id=$id");//Post $id to page2.php   
?>
```

**`Page2.php`**

```
<?php
      echo $user_id=$_GET['id']; //should receive id posted from page1.php
?>
```

Comment: @user3245689, You cannot make use of `POST` here. Make use of `cURL` for that :)

Comment: Have a look at what I did to use a `POST` method in my answer below. I edited it this morning and it works/tested. @user3245689

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) for this also, to show you what your options are.

This works with a **POST** method (use all in one file for the form method)

Form method (page1.php)

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION["id"] = $_POST['id'];

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
echo $id;
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href='page2.php'>Click to see session ID on next page</a>";
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">

Enter ID: 
<input type="text" name="id">

<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$user_id=$_SESSION["id"];
echo $user_id; // will echo 1234 if you entered "1234" in the previous page.
```

---

Regular session method (page1.php)

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION["id"] = "1234";
echo $id; // will echo 1234
```

page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$user_id=$_SESSION["id"];
echo $user_id; // will echo 1234
```

---

**Footnotes:**
You could then use the same (session) variable for a member's login area, database for example.

It is **important** to keep `session_start();` included inside all pages using sessions, and at the top.

Should you be using a [`header()`](http://www.php.net/header) in conjunction with this, then you will need to add [`ob_start();`](http://www.php.net/ob_start) before [`session_start();`](http://www.php.net/session_start)

Otherwise (as Eitan stated in a comment) "`$_SESSION` *value will be unresolvable."*

`header()` example:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$user_id=$_SESSION["id"];

   if(isset($_SESSION["id"])){
header("Location: members_page.php");
   exit;
}

   else{
header("Location: login_page.php");
   exit;
}
```

You could also replace: `if(isset($_SESSION["id"]))` with `if(!empty($_SESSION["id"]))`

To implement a logout page, you would need to use [`session_destroy();`](http://www.php.net/session_destroy)

Comment: Good thing is not forgetting "session_start();", otherwise $_SESSION value will be unresolvable.

Comment: You made a good point, I will add an note to that effect, thank you. `+1` on comment. @Eitan